# How do I disable the image source replacement in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile and I'm facing a problem with loading images on my site.

Jquery mobile adds my base href to the beginning of the image source making my source wrong..

How can I disable this?

Comment: Can you show us a code example?

Comment: There isn't really any code to show.. src="images/test.png" is replaced with src="http://domain.com/images/test.png"

Comment: Again this is simply not enough. How can you expect someone to give you an answer without showing what you have done.

Comment: If you knew jquery mobile you would know about the issue. The question does not need any code sample. Period.

Comment: So? Go to github and you will see that it is a well known issue.

Comment: If that is so, you will find your answer there.

Comment: Nope.. It's not resolved yet.. Thats why Im asking.. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/wiki/Refactor:-navigation-paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

After crawling the web for a solution for a couple of days I finally found something that helped.

I downloaded the uncompressed source code of jquery mobile and replaced the variable "newPath" with the following code:

```
var newPath = path.get( $('head base').attr('href') );
```

Works like a charm!